# meteor moment timezone not working

Tags: meteor, timezone, momentjs

i got the error : 
Exception in template helper: TypeError: time.tz is not a function

with the code :

```
Template.registerHelper( 'timeAgo', function ( timestamp ) {
if ( timestamp ) {
let time   = moment( timestamp ),
let timezone =  Session.get("timezone");

return  time.tz(timezone).fromNow();
}
});
```

i have installed the momentjs:moment and it works fine.

the problem is with the timezone package : i have installed the aldeed:moment-timezone package , then i tried with the mrt:moment-timezone package but nothing ; it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you loaded **moment** using something like:

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

instead of:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```